# WPF Z-index issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF `Canvas` and there are 3 WPF user controls on it. All of them have a Z-index set, like 1, 2, or 3. One of the user controls contains a web browser control.

After this I add the `Rectangle` WPF control to the `Canvas` with a Z-index of 100.

The issue is that the user control which contains the web browser and has a Z-index of 2 is visible but the others aren't (because of the black rectangle). But it shouldn't work like that, the UserControl has a Z-index of 2!

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: to @minitech Thanks for the English corrections! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that WebBrowser has airspace concerns.  You can't overlay content on top of a WebBrowser control.

For details, see the [WPF Interop page on Airspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well... Thank you for the really FAST answer!!! Then... I will set up this User Control which has Web Browser like HIDDEN...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can add any content on top of a web browser. You need to place the content inside a Popup inside its own Canvas, like this:

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="False">
   <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" ClipToBounds="False" IsOpen="True">
      <Rectangle x:Name="YourContent"/>
   <Popup>
</Canvas>
```

You may replace the Rectagle with any control, it will be displayed on top of the browser and even outside the parent window.

Here's a screenshot illustrating this, in this case what overlaps the webbrowser is a listbox with a special style to make it look like a menu popup:

[image]